# How to use node.io for HTML parsing from node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, npm, node.io

I am trying to use `node.io` on `node.js` to parse a HTML page which i have as a string in a variable.

I am facing trouble with passing the HTML string to my `node.io` job as an argument.

This is an excerpt of my code at my node file `nodeiotest.js`:

```
var nodeIOJob   =    require('./nodeiojobfile.js');
var nodeio = require('node.io');

vat htmlString = 'HTML String Here';

nodeio.start(nodeIOJob.job, function(err, output) {
        console.log(output);
}, true);
```

The next is an excerpt of my file `nodeiojobfile.js`:

```
var nodeio = require('node.io');

var methods = {
   input: ['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'],    // htmlString is suppossed to come here
   run: function (num) {
       console.log(num);
       this.emit('Hello World!');
   }
}

exports.job = new nodeio.Job(methods);
```

How do I send my `htmlString` as argument to my job in the other file?

Also, after receiving the file i need to parse it as an HTML and perform some basic CSS selection (ex. getElementById() etc.) and need to calculate `offsetHeight` of certain HTML elements. The documentation says I can use `get()` and `getHTML()` methods to parse a URL's html but what about HTML in a string? How do I parse them?

For testing purposes I am using he following HTML:

```
<div>
    <p id="p1">
        Testing document
    </p>
</div>
```

I am trying to select the `<p>` and then find out its height.

Can anyone help me?
Thnx in advance!!

Comment: Well, after hours of wrecking my brain and my keyboard keys I have decided that it cannot be done, atleast not without making it a very inefficient task.... kindly let me know if anyone finds a light-weight solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `node.io`, but I think you want something like this:

```
// nodeiotest.js
...
var htmlString = 'HTML String Here';
nodeio.start(nodeIOJob.job(htmlString), function(err, output) {
  console.log(output);
}, true);

// nodeiojobfile.js
var nodeio = require('node.io');

module.exports.job = function(htmlString) { 
  var methods = {
    input: [ htmlString ],
    run  : function (num) { 
      console.log(num);
      this.emit('Hello World!');
    }
  };
  return new nodeio.Job(methods);
};
```

Comment: thnx robert but a bigger problem for me is to find the height of an element on the server side, i couldn't seem to do it with node.io and jsdom also has a bug regarding it..... could you suggest a solution for this, maybe a server side headless browser like phantomjs or something similar....

Comment: @SurenderThakran yes you're going to have to use a browser-like solution for that (like PhantomJS which you mention).

Comment: I was afraid of this. Can you suggest any such browser compatible with `node.js`? PhantomJS does not comes as a node module and had to be used as a child process, I am not sure how to get height of an element if I am running a headless browser in the command-line.

Comment: @SurenderThakran perhaps [zombie](https://npmjs.org/package/zombie), but I'm not sure if it implements actual rendering (to get dimensions)

Comment: thnx will give it a shot!!